# UIWebView or Custom UIView

Tags: iphone

I have a dilemma and was wondering if anyone else had this issue.  I have a Navigation based app that when you drill down to the last level, that last view has lots and lots of information and details.  I am wondering if I should just use a UIWebView to display the details of information or if I should create a custom UIView with all the labels and outlets set in that UIView.  Which way is recommended or the preferred way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the amount and type of data that should be displayed.

Notice that you can't set transparent background for UIWebView, so if you have a custom background for the entire application then it might be harder to implement in web view.

You might also use the Three20 library.
TTView might also be a good solution.